# Making a data type iterable within a Polymer element in Dart

Tags: dart, polymer

I have a custom data type in Dart that I would like to make iterable using `template repeat`. Here are stripped-down versions of the data types in question:

```dart
class Note {
  String content;
  Note(this.content);
}

class Notebook {
  List<Note> notes;
  Notebook(this.notes);
}
```

I want to be able to iterate through the `Note`s in a `Notebook` like so:

```dart
<polymer-element name="x-notebook=view">
  <ul>
    <template repeat="{{note in notebook}}">
      <li is="x-note-view" note="{{note}}></li>
    </template>
  </ul>

  <script ...></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The problem, of course, is that standard `List`s can be iterated through in this way, but I'm not sure how to modify my custom `Notebook` data type to do the same.

One way that *does* seem to work is to attach a `toList()` method to the `Notebook` class:

```dart
List<Note> toList() => notes;
```

But I was hoping to make this possible without first converting to a `List`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the source of `polymer_expression` package reveals that the right side of the `in` operator has to be an `Iterable`, so you have to implement this interface.

I did a quick test and the following seems to work:

```dart
import 'dart:collection' show IterableMixin;

// [IterableMixin] implement all methods of [Iterable]
// in terms of [iterator].
class Notebook extends Object with IterableMixin<Note> {
  List<Note> notes;
  Notebook(this.notes);

  get iterator => notes.iterator;
}
```